# How to fetch unique values for a single column in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my `products` table, each `Product` has a column called `retailer`. In my view, I am trying to fetch and display all *unique* values for that `retailer` column from the table. Note that I only need distinct values for ONE single column, i.e. `retailer`. Here's my attempt:

```
@foreach(\App\Product::select('retailer')->groupBy('retailer')->get() as $retailer)
    {{$retailer->retailer}}
@endforeach
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228823/laravel-get-distinct-values-for-non-key-column-fields) I've read that `groupBy('retailers)` would get the unique values. That indeed worked, but since I am passing an array `$products` to the view, which contains all products, I thought looping through `$products` would be more efficient:

```
 @foreach($products->select('retailer')->unique() as $retailer)
     {{$retailer}}
 @endforeach
```

but that didn't work.

**Q**: What am I doing wrong here? Is there a more efficient way to go about this? Is it better to resort to Query Builder (rather than Eloquent) in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `->distinct('retailer')`

Comment: This should've worked too: `$products->unique('retailer')->pluck('retailer')`; no need to make a separate query.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@foreach(App\Product::distinct()->get(['retailer']) as $product)
    {{$product->retailer}}
@endforeach
```

**EDIT**

Of course you can. In your controller

```
$products = App\Product::distinct()->get(['retailer']);
foreach($products as $product) {
    // do your magic
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I could loop through the `$products` array instead that I pass with the view?