# Laravel where and orWhere function

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I'm trying to count how many tickets our operators have closed in a week(and per day) I have these 2 queries

```
    $closedWeek = Ticket::join('activity_log', 'activity_log.rel_id', '=', 'ticket.id')
                ->where([
                    ['activity_log.created_at',  '>', $fri],
                    ['activity_log.user_id', '=', $id],
                    ['activity_log.event_name', '=', 'ticket_closed'],
                    ['number', 'like', 'SD%']
                ])->count();

    $closedWeek2 = Ticket::join('activity_log', 'activity_log.rel_id', '=', 'ticket.id')
                ->where([
                    ['activity_log.created_at',  '>', $fri],
                    ['activity_log.user_id', '=', $id],
                    ['number', 'like', 'SD%'],
                    ['activity_log.event_name', '=', 'ticket_department_updated']
                ])
                ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('activity_log.new_value', '=', 'closed Uninvoiced')
                        ->orWhere('activity_log.new_value', '=', 'To Invoice')
                        ->orWhere('activity_log.new_value', '=', 'closed Other')
                        ->orWhere('activity_log.new_value', '=', 'closed Invoiced');
                })->count();
    $closedWeek = $closedWeek + $closedWeek2;
```

They are bringing back slightly bigger numbers than expected and I think some of them are duplicated. How could I put these into one query using where(function($query)) or do I have to use DB::raw instead? I can then count unique ids

Comment: This looks well suited for a `whereIn()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GroupBy();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) with id,

Example:

```
$closedWeek = Ticket::join('activity_log', 'activity_log.rel_id', '=', 'ticket.id')
                ->where([
                    ['activity_log.created_at',  '>', $fri],
                    ['activity_log.user_id', '=', $id],
                    ['activity_log.event_name', '=', 'ticket_closed'],
                    ['number', 'like', 'SD%']
                ])
                ->groupBy('ticket.id')
                ->count();

    $closedWeek2 = Ticket::join('activity_log', 'activity_log.rel_id', '=', 'ticket.id')
                ->where([
                    ['activity_log.created_at',  '>', $fri],
                    ['activity_log.user_id', '=', $id],
                    ['number', 'like', 'SD%'],
                    ['activity_log.event_name', '=', 'ticket_department_updated']
                ])
                ->whereIn('activity_log.new_value', 
                    [   'closed Uninvoiced', 
                        'To Invoice',
                        'closed Other',
                        'closed Invoiced',
                ])
                ->groupBy('ticket.id')
                ->count();
$closedWeek = $closedWeek + $closedWeek2;
```

**OBS:**

> You dont need `'=',` on equal wheres, **example**, `where('colun', '=', 'abc');` you can change to `where('colun', 'abc');`

Please test and see if you have the expected result.

References:

[How to get distinct values for non-key column fields in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228823/how-to-get-distinct-values-for-non-key-column-fields-in-laravel)