# is There A Laravel PHP Function To Show Database Records Without Duplicates?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to be able to bring back records from an SQL stored procedure and display them. but I do not want to show duplicates.

I have stored a procedure that brings back all records where ID = the selected ID.
It then displays something like this

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 12 | 34 |
| 12 | 33 |
| 12 | 33 |

I need to bring back only one occurence where ID = 12 and value = 33, and one occurence where ID = 12 and value = 34

I'm working in a PHP laravel framework, I know  that

`DB::selectOne` will bring back a single column, and that `DB::select` will bring back all records. Is there a laravel/PHP function that will bring back records and will only show one of each value? like so:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 12 | 33 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get distinct values for non-key column fields in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228823/how-to-get-distinct-values-for-non-key-column-fields-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. To display a single occurrence, you must use "distinct"

```
$result = DB::table('YourTableName')
->select('id', '//other columns')
->distinct()
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through MYSQL:

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY col2, col3;
```

or something like that though Eloquent:

```
$data = Model::select('id', 'value')->groupBy(['id', 'value'])->get;
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. `groupBy` is the best option here, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct as shown in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements).
Distinct will remove the duplicate records.

```
$data = DB::table('{{table_name}}')->select('id', 'desired_column')->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy()` which will remove your duplicate record and read it as a single record. You have to use `Select()` before `groupBy()`. I.e. `select('require name')` then `groupBy('require name')`.

```
TABLENAME::Select('require name')->groupBy('require name')->get();
```