# How get rows that have unique agent_key in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I do not know how to select rows that `agent_key` is unique. I used `groupBy` and `distinct` to do this, but I did not succeed.

This is my table:

[image]

Comment: How did you use `groupBy` and `distinct` ? Maybe share your code?

Comment: $query = distinct()->select('agent_key');

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228908/3532758

Comment: This link (stackoverflow.com/a/25228908/3532758) didn't return complete row.

Comment: try ModelName::groupBy('agent_key ')->havingRaw('count(agent_key )=1')->get();

Answer (score 0):

```
YourModal::get()->unique('agent_key');
```

Comment: I can't use unique

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::unique()

Comment: Let me know your laravel version and share your code

Comment: Please Share Your Code

Comment: $query = DB::table('agents')-> distinct()->select('agent_key')->get();
Or
$query = DB::table('agents')-> distinct('agent_key)->get();

Comment: When I try to use "SELECT DISTINCT `agent_key` FROM `agents`" this query doesn't return completed row

Comment: Did you try with model ?